# Multiplot overlays plots

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to make simple multiplot of two plots in two rows in a single column, but I always get both graphs printed on top of each other on first row and second plot on row 2 like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Hoq.png)

My code looks like this:

```
clear
set encoding utf8
reset session
set multiplot layout 2,1 title "Multiplot layout" font "Consolas,18"
set title "Magnitúda" font "Consolas,18"
NO_ANIMATION = 1
set ylabel "x [-]" font "Consolas,14"
set xlabel "t [s]" font "Consolas,14"
set xrange [0:15]
set yrange [0:1.1]
set grid
show grid
set key off

plot 'spect.dat' using 1:2 with impulses lw 3 lc rgb "black" notitle
#
set title "Fáza" font "Consolas,18"
set yrange [0:190]
plot 'spect.dat' using 1:3 with impulses lw 3 lc rgb "black" notitle
replot
```

When I commented out second plot command it did not happen, but there was second plot but without line.

my data:

```
#f  amp phase
1   1   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
10  0.2 180
```

What could be causing this? How may I solve this?

Comment: Remove the `replot`, it repeats the preceeding plot